# How to turn off the caching functionality in smarty

Tags: caching, smarty

I want to turn-off caching functionality in smarty. I have tried using the following code

```
$smarty->caching = true;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;
```

But the above  code would not work.

How can i turn-off caching.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: In smarty 3, $smarty->setCaching(Smarty::CACHING_OFF);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn it off, you need to set:

```
 $smart->caching = Smarty::CACHING_OFF;
```

and not

```
 $smarty->caching = true;
```

as you showed in your question